# @Value injection of field not working in case of an empty Map

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection, application.properties

I am trying to inject a map property inside my spring-component class using @Value annotation.

My class is something like this

```
@Service
class SomeService {
    @Value("#{\${some.map.property}}")
    lateinit var map: Map<String, Boolean>
}
```

If my application.properties is as -

```
some.map.property={a:true}
```

The injection works fine. But if the value is empty i.e. something like this

```
some.map.property={}
```

The application throws an error `lateinit property map has not been initialised`. Is there a way in spring to initialise the map to an empty map if the value of the property is `{}`.I have a condition that this property will always be there and only the value of the property can change. I am using spring boot version -> 2.7.1 and the app is built using Kotlin.

If the property is set to {}, then I am getting property uninitialised error. If the value is present it works fine.
Given I always have to keep the property and can only change the value. Is there a way to initialise the property with an empty map if the value is {}.
I can always read the property as string and do a conversion to Map. But I want to avoid that.

Thanks!

Comment: Any specific reason to use lateinit keyword? I tried without lateinit keyword and it is working fine without any issue

Answer (score 1):

So the problem with your code is that whenever you pass:

```
some.map.property={}
```

You will receive:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property map has not been initialized
```

Because `{}` is mapped to null, but you are expecting to have  `Map<String, Boolean>` that's why you have a problem.

The solution is simple, you can use the default value if null occurs:

```
    @Value("#{\${some.map.property}}")
    val map: Map<String, Boolean> = emptyMap()
```

In that case for `{}` value in your property it will be mapped to empty map.